# Clear instruction in MIPS: clear $t0

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

what does the instruction clear $t0 perform in MIPS?I mean what is the actual MIPS instruction for this pseudo-instruction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does this:

```
add  $t0, $zero, $zero
```

Edit: I found a reference [here](http://www.academic.marist.edu/~jzbv/architecture/Homework/HW2MIPSInstructionsAns.htm).